# PHP - AJAX and MySQL

Tags: php, ajax

This is my code:

```
<?php

$q=$_GET["q"];

require("../db.php");

$res_prop_name = mysql_query("select * from property where prop_short='$q'");

$row_prop_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_prop_name);

echo $row_prop_name['prop_name'];

?>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showProperty(str)    
{

if (str=="")  
{

      document.getElementById("prop_name").innerHTML="";

      return;

}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

}

else    
{// code for IE6, IE5

    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");    
}



xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()    
{

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

    {    
        document.getElementById("prop_name").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;    
    }

}

xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/get-property-name.php?q="+str,true);

xmlhttp.send();

}

</script>
```

---

```
<select id="prop_short" name="prop_short" onchange="showProperty(this.value)">

<option value="">Select a property</option>

<option value="Property2">Property1</option>

<option value="Property2">Property2</option>

</select>

<input type="text" id="prop_name" name="prop_name" onChange="showProperty(this.value)">
```

The answer to my question must be very simple however I just can't make it work.

I understand that in the ajax script the innerHTML feeds the text into a div that has the id prop_name for example. I tried it and it worked. But how can I feed the returned text into a input type="text" field? I've tried innerText instead of HTML but it doesnt work.

Comment: For input elements it's document.getElementById("xxx").value instead of .innerHTML

Comment: There you go. already set as an answer. Glad it worked! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the comment as an answer: For input elements it's document.getElementById("xxx").value instead of .innerHTML.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? My problem now that in one of the fields I need to feed in the property name and into the other one the property owner. How can I do both? i tried to create 2 ajax functions and 2 php query files but the onchange="showPropertyName(this.value)" onchange="showPropertyOwner(this.value)" doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: You could do it with one SQL query, getting the two values from the query and updating the two fields at once. 
If you choose to do it separately, you can use one unique php that selects prop_name, prop_owner from property with an if-else [code] if ($_GET["r"] == 1) { echo $row_prop_name['prop_name'];} elseif($_GET["r"]== 2) {echo $row_prop_name['prop_owner'];} [/code] ... then, your two JS functions just need to get the data the way it is getting it now because there's only one output for the php. Hope it is somehow clear!

Comment: I appreciate your help. Many thanks for it. I figured the same. I put it in the same function it's working now. Thanks again for the quick response. Cheers